# Parsing div children with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm using beautiful soup to find and parse street addresses on a page.
Ultimately I'd like to write the street addresses into an excel document.

Here is the page I'm trying to parse: https://montreal.lufa.com/en/pick-up-points

The page in question has div elements listed at the same level beneath a class. I've been unable to parse the individual rows. Instead my code just spits out everything in under the class.

My code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import urllib2

URL = "https://montreal.lufa.com/en/pick-up-points"
html = urllib2.urlopen(URL).read().decode('UTF-8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")

business = (soup.find('div', class_="info"))

print (business)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following: for every business, locate the open days and get [every previous sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-previous-siblings-and-find-previous-sibling):

```
for business in soup.find_all('div', class_="info"):
    days = business.find("div", class_="days")

    print(" ".join(sibling.get_text(strip=True) 
                   for sibling in reversed(days.find_previous_siblings())))
```

Prints:

```
1600, René-Lévesque west 1600, René-Lévesque west Montreal, Quebec H3H 1P9
555 Chabanel Street West 555 Chabanel Street West Montreal, Quebec H2N 2H8
À la Boîte à Fleurs 3266 Saint-Rose Boulevard Laval, Quebec H7P 4K8
Allez Up Centre d'escalade 1555 St-Patrick Montreal, Quebec H3K 2B7
...
YMCA Cartierville 11885 Laurentien Boulevard Montreal, Quebec H4J 2R5
Zone, Real estate Agency 200 rue St-Jean Longueuil, Quebec J4H 2X5
```

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Cool, alecxe!  Here's what I did to make it work on my machine . . . .

```
#1)  In Console:  
pip install lxml


#2)  Run script below:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import urllib2

URL = "https://montreal.lufa.com/en/pick-up-points"
html = urllib2.urlopen(URL).read().decode('UTF-8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

#business = (soup.find('div', class_="info"))
for business in soup.find_all('div', class_="info"):
    days = business.find("div", class_="days")

    print(" ".join(sibling.get_text(strip=True) 
                   for sibling in reversed(days.find_previous_siblings())))
print (business)
```